# Creating Sharepoint Reports in SSRS - Direct SQL -> Web Services -> Object Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

For some time now I've been struggling to find the best option for reporting on SharePoint list data using SSRS reports (Sharepoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2).

**Part 1 - Confession Time**

Initially, I very skilfully managed to avoid all of the advice saying DO NOT query the SharePoint database directly from SQL ... so I ended up with several SQL views that do just that i.e. query the SP database directly. These SQL views provide data for stored procedures which are in turn called by the SSRS reports so I'm looking for a way to re-write the views properly without having to change the stored procedures and reports.

**Part 2 - A False Dawn calling SharePoint Web Services from a SQL CLR Function**

To rectify my mistake from Part 1, I decided I needed to re-write the SQL views and decided to go down the path detailed here:-

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1546/how-to-call-a-sharepoint-web-service-from-a-sql-server-clr-function/

- the problem I'm finding is with performance e.g. whilst a call to the List.asmx GetListCollection() method is pretty quick, calls to GetListItems() are taking considerably longer, typically around 250ms per call. The problem here is that I need to call GetListItems() for each sub-site of the main site - i.e. each sub-site has a list that I need data from and given that there could be several hundred sub-sites all those 250ms add up to pretty poor performance.

**Part 3 - Possible Salvation using the SharePoint Object Model**

My current thinking is to use the method detailed here:-

http://www.sharepointjohn.com/technology/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-sql-server-2008-query-the-sharepoint-object-model-from-a-net-sql-server-clr-function/

My questions are:-

1) Will using the Sharepoint object model provide better performance than the web services ? (I'm wondering if the object model provides a better way of cycling through all of the sub-sites and getting the data I require from the lists).

2) Step 11 of the link above requires loading lots of .NET assemblies into SQL - does this have an affect on SQL Server itself ? Apologies if that's a stupid question but I really am running out of knowledge at this point and am very wary of making changes like this to a production server, I just don't understand what happens when an assembly is loaded into SQL.

3) Am I completely barking up the wrong tree with all this ?!?! As you may have gathered I'm a rather junior developer (in knowledge more than years !) and at times like this can't see the wood for the trees.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Many Thanks :-)